# Recover ram used by lightdm when not using it

Tags: lightdm, ram

What is the difference between these three commands:

```
sudo systemctl stop lightdm.service
```

or

```
sudo lightdm stop
```

or

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

I'm setting up a command line server with the possibility to start lxde when needed. I've edited grub file, and it boots directly to the command line. Problem comes when I start an X session. when I close it, ram goes down by a tiny bit. But when i run this command:

```
sudo systemctl disable lightdm.service
```

Xserver closes AND ram goes down by a good 150MB, which I prefer that way. Problem is that it seems that if I want to close the xserver and get that ram back, only this works.

1. Do I have to use this command over the command 1, 2 or 3 stated above?
2. Can I corrupt the system or something using that one?

Comment: Why asking? Do what works!! That said, first three stops lightdm while the last one disables lightdm to start at boot .You don't need lightdm to start at boot anyway. And even lightdm is unnecessary if you're only running a single xsession. You can directly start lxde from console.

Comment: yes, at least its working but ill post if i find what im doing^^

Answer (score 0):

I answer myself in case someone has the same questions, completing Anwar's answer:

- `service` is a wrapper for `systemctl`, so its the same
- you don't corrupt anything by closing lightdm, in fact, is desirable for a command line server.